# how to read an .xlsx file link that was open in google sheets with Appscripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that im not the owner, it was an excel file imported to drive and opened with google sheets, i want to import the data automatically to another sheet using a script that i made as a work around so i don't need to use that .xlsx sheet.

But i can't find a way to read that sheet data using Appscript.

[image]

Here's the script i have so far:

```
function rePlaceSheet () {
let source = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('14rIrUEOpLNWfQjIW29v1Zc9eDkaomMBx').getSheetByName('sheet1');
let target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet('1xjW28VmFypAOjHi_FJ_7MGCigGrIIp-AgTkfuR7m7QQ').getSheetByName('sheet1');
let sRange = source.getDataRange();
let A1Range = sRange.getA1Notation();
let rawData = sRange.getValues();

target.clear({contentsOnly: true});
target.getRange(A1Range).setValues(rawData); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current stage, unfortunately, the XLSX file cannot be directly retrieved with Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and Sheets API. So, in this case, it is required to convert the XLSX file to a Google Spreadsheet. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function rePlaceSheet() {
  const fileIdOfXLSXFile = "14rIrUEOpLNWfQjIW29v1Zc9eDkaomMBx";
  const convertedFileId = Drive.Files.copy({ title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, fileIdOfXLSXFile, { supportsAllDrives: true }).id;
  let source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedFileId).getSheetByName('sheet1');
  let target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet('1xjW28VmFypAOjHi_FJ_7MGCigGrIIp-AgTkfuR7m7QQ').getSheetByName('sheet1');
  let sRange = source.getDataRange();
  let A1Range = sRange.getA1Notation();
  let rawData = sRange.getValues();
  target.clear({ contentsOnly: true });
  target.getRange(A1Range).setValues(rawData);
  DriveApp.getFileById(convertedFileId).setTrashed(true); //  or Drive.Files.remove(convertedFileId, { supportsAllDrives: true });
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that your file ID of `'14rIrUEOpLNWfQjIW29v1Zc9eDkaomMBx'` is the file of XLSX file. Please be careful about this.
- When this script is run, the XLSX file of `'14rIrUEOpLNWfQjIW29v1Zc9eDkaomMBx'` is converted to a Google Spreadsheet. And, the values are retrieved from the converted Spreadsheet and copied to the destination sheet.
- By the way, if the sheet name of "sheet1" is not existing in your XLSX file, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/copy)
- [Method: files.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/delete)

Comment: It worked partially, i can't make a copy of a xlxs sheet that's in another person drive

Comment: @Vinicius Oliveira Thank you for replying. About `It worked partially, i can't make a copy of a xlxs sheet that's in another person drive`, if you have the permission of the files in the other user's drive. But, if you have no permission of them, you cannot copy them. I deeply apologize for this situation.